# Is it possible to do a bisect search in Github

Tags: github, bisect

### Background

I've been working in Github lately. But with all of this Travis-ci and stuff, I've been trying to debug code like crazy. I know about the `git bisect` git command. And since I've been trying to stuff on Github lately, I though, "Hmm, does Github have a graphical equivalent  to `git bisect`?"

### Question

But so far, I haven't found a bisect search option in Github. **Is it even possible in the GitHub website (in-browser)?** Or do I have to use the command-line?

Comment: I'm on an iPhone, so posting a well formatted answer that doesn't seem like a cheap "nope" isn't that easy, so I'll refrain from doing that. But duly noted, I've removed my comment and I'll avoid commenting your questions in the future.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Oh. Understandable.

Comment: AFAIK, no. If you tell us why you're looking for a Github bisect, and what issues you're having with `git-bisect`, we may be able to make `git-bisect` work for you.

Comment: Could you tell us why you want to run a bisect exclusively in your browser? If it's the command line putting you off, perhaps there is a bisect app. Note that in order for bisect to be useful on Github, Github (or a connected service) would need to be able to execute your code. You mentioned Travis-CI, how is it related?